# HTML5 slideshow not displaying in Chrome (and Safari).

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, slideshow

Peeps,

running into an issue, where I am building a website and my slide show is not displaying in Chrome (34.0) and apparently Safari either (not sure of version).  Runs well in Firefox (28.0) and IE 11.0  even works on HTC browser

The slide show is located right below the nav bar (   ,........

Code:

```
<div class="css-slideshow">

<figure>
<img src="images/slide_pic01_orange.jpg" alt="class-header-css3" width="980" height="300" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-172" />
<figcaption><strong>Connectivity:&nbsp;</strong> lorem ipsum</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
<img src="images/slide_pic02_orange.jpg" alt="class-header-semantics" width="980" height="300" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-179" />
<figcaption><strong>Website design:&nbsp;</strong>lorem ipsum</figcaption> 
</figure>

<figure>
<img src="images/slide_pic03_orange.jpg" alt="class-header-offline" width="980" height="300" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-178" />
<figcaption><strong>IP Telephony:&nbsp;</strong>lorem ipsum</figcaption> 
</figure>

</div>
```

I have tried Chrome web inspector to get some of the errors out,

the other thing that does not work is the gradient colors in the nav bar that go from white (top) to orange (bottom). It only works with gradient colors in Firefox.

CSS:

```
nav ul {
background: #ff6600; 
background: linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #ff6600 100%);  
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%, #ff6600 100%); 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#ff600 100%); 
box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
padding: 0 75x;
border-radius: 10px;
list-style: none;
position: relative;
display: inline-table;
z-index: 9999;
```

For the life of me i have run out of options on how to diagnose this.

*Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/charliebabbit/ULvXS/

*URL:

http://www.dogtel.com.au/test.html

Thanks guys

Comment: I fixed it, i forgot to double up my animations with the -webkit element in my CSS file.

Comment: as for the navbar gradient colors, I removed the percentages and that fixed it.